# How to access variables declared in initialize of a view in functions defined below in same view senchatouch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a variable declared in initialize part of the view.When I try to access this variable in the function which is declared in a panel I am getting an error that the variable is undefined.I have tried accessing it by 1>this.variablename 2>viewid.variablename....what am i doing wrong?

```
Ext.define('app.view.location', {
            extend : 'Ext.Panel',
            xtype : 'location_d',
            id : 'locdetail',
            initialize : function() {
                loc = 'abc';
            },
            config : {
                layout : {
                    type : 'card'
                },
                scrollable : true,
                fullscreen : true,
                items : [{
                            xtype : 'panel',
                            html : 'Get Dir',
                            id : 'Dir',
                            cls : 'loc',
                            listeners : {
                                tap : {
                                    element : 'element',
                                    fn : function(m) {
                                        alert(this.loc); //gives me undefined variable error
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }]
            }
        });
```

Comment: In this case, it's better to add your code to the post so we can really see what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ext.define('app.view.location', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'location_d',
 id:'locdetail',
 initialize:function(){

          loc='abc';
         }

 config: {
  layout: 
                {
   type: 'card'
  },
  scrollable:true,
  fullscreen:true,
  items:[
   {
    xtype:'panel',
    html:'Get Dir',
    id:'Dir',
    cls:'loc',
    listeners: 
    {
       tap: 
     {
      element: 'element',
      fn: function(m)
      {
           alert(this.loc);
           //gives me undefined variable error      
                
      }
     }
    },
      
    },
  } 
                    ]}

Answer (score 6):

There are a few mistakes in your code.

First you need to add *loc* als variable in your config.

```
config : {
    layout : {
        type : 'card'
    },
    loc: null,
    scrollable : true,
    ...}
```

Then you should set loc with his setter.

```
initialize : function() {
    this.setLoc("abc");
},
```

In your tap-listener, you can't work with **this**, because it references to the inner panel and not to the outer, use the ComponenetManager to get the outer panel.

```
listeners : {
    tap : {
        element : 'element',
        fn : function(m) {
            alert(Ext.ComponentManager.get("locdetail").getLoc());
        }
    }
}
```

I tried it and it works without a problem!

Full Code:

```
Ext.define('app.view.location', {
    extend : 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype : 'location_d',
    id : 'locdetail',
    initialize : function() {
        this.setLoc("abc");
    },
    config : {
        layout : {
            type : 'card'
        },
        loc: null,
        scrollable : true,
        fullscreen : true,
        items : [{
            xtype : 'panel',
            html : 'Get Dir',
            id : 'Dir',
            cls : 'loc',
            listeners : {
                tap : {
                    element : 'element',
                    fn : function(m) {
                        alert(Ext.ComponentManager.get("locdetail").getLoc());
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

Sencha Touch Class System Guide: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/class_system

Comment: Then please accept this answer, so that other user know it worked.